# error while sending sms using java using twillo app

Tags: java, sms, twilio, noclassdeffounderror, twilio-api

I am trying to send SMS from java web application using Twillo app. But I am getting the following error at Glassfish server 4.1.1

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
 org/apache/http/conn/HttpClientConnectionManager
```

at

```
 Message message = Message.creator(new PhoneNumber(""),
```

I have added Twilio 7.41.2 jar in my netbeans ide library folder. But I 
     have not added any maven dependency in pom.xml as this is not maven enabled the project, is this the error due to missing maven dependency?

```
  index.jsp

  <form action="sms" method="post">
  <input type ="submit"/>
  </form>

  Servlet sms.java

  import com.twilio.Twilio;
  import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message;
  import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.PrintWriter;
  import javax.servlet.ServletException;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
  response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

  try{

  final String ACCOUNT_SID = "myaccountsid";
  final String AUTH_TOKEN = "my string authtoken";

  Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

  Message message = Message.creator(new PhoneNumber("recipient phone no"),
  new PhoneNumber("recipient phone no"),"Hello This is Tom").create();

  out.println(message.getSid());


    processRequest(request, response);

    }
 catch(IOException | ServletException e){


  }
  }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the `Apache HttpClient Library` to your project path? In this case, I think you are not.

`NoClassDefFoundError` will come if a class was present during compile time but not available in java classpath during runtime. Normally you will see below line in log when you get,

> NoClassDefFoundError: Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

So according to your error,

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/http/conn/HttpClientConnectionManager

you are missing the `Apache HttpClient Library`.

So please add the `.jar` file in your project library. You can download this `jar` file from the Maven Repository.

[Download from Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient)

Note: To run this application with `twilio` I guess you need to add more libraries according to the [Twilio Documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/java). Check this [GitHub link](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java/blob/master/pom.xml) to get know about what libraries need to add to the project if your application throws error again after adding the `Apache HttpClient Library`.

Comment: Ok thanks ...sorry for late comment.. i am adding your mentioned jar file..lets see